# Salesforce grouping execution flow

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, governorlimits, platform-event

Is possible Salesforce be agroupping the Lighting flow execution?

We are working with Platform events calling a specific Lightning flow each time it runs, and we noticed the flows are being executed together in the same transaction.

It seems SFDC is grouping the flow execution, as it is for the same flow. Is that possible?

Thanks,

Tiago

Comment: a batch of platform events should execute the associated flow in the same transaction as a bulk operation although the flow is built to look like it is only handling one event.

Comment: thanks @copredy